# ping Amazon.com gives 100% packet loss on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: ping, amazon-web-services

I am trying to ping external links from AWS EC2 instance but result is 100% packet loss.

Amazon.com, Microsoft.com -> 100% packet loss

Google.com -> 100% packet sent

Why my AWS instance can't ping Amazon.com, Microsoft.com but can ping Google.com? Is there anything to configure?

Comment: Even not able to make java http request to these hosts.. Is there any way to make http request through some java/php client?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is normal. Currently on my desktop I get the same results. This is because Microsoft and Amazon block ICMP ping requests in their firewalls. However Google allow ICMP ping requests.

Regarding HTTP, I did a `curl` on microsoft.com and amazon.com

Microsoft reply with:

> Your current User-Agent string appears to be from an automated
>   process.

Amazon reply with:

> To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact
>   api-services-support@amazon.com.

From this we can see that Amazon and Microsoft are rejecting non-browser based HTTP(S) connections.

Comment: [I wouldn't be so sure...](http://i.imgur.com/XefEstc.png)

Comment: I have clarified my answer. I did say that Microsoft and Amazon block these requests, but I never said that google allows them.

Comment: You're good. Marked as answer. :)